# Use pnpm in diferent Gitlab CI stages

Tags: gitlab-ci, pnpm

I'm struggling with `Gitlab CI` and `pnpm`. I have a simple pipeline with `npm`, two stages, install and test, using cache:

```yaml
stages:
  - install
  - test

install:
  stage: install
  tags:
      - node:LTS
  script:
    - npm install
  cache:
    key: node_modules
    paths:
      - node_modules
  only:
    - develop

test:
  stage: test
  tags:
      - node:LTS
  cache:
    key: node_modules
    paths:
      - node_modules
    policy: pull
  coverage: /All files[^|]*\|[^|]*\s+([\d\.]+)/
  dependencies:
    - install
  script:
    - npm run test:ci
  only:
    - develop
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit: coverage/junit-report.xml
      coverage_report: 
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: coverage/coverage-final.json
```

This works perfectly fine, and I want to take advantage of `pnpm` and start using it. According to the docs, I modified my code as follows:

```yaml
install:
  stage: install
  tags:
      - node:LTS
  before_script:
    - corepack enable
    - corepack prepare pnpm@latest-7 --activate
    - pnpm config set store-dir .pnpm-store
  script:
    - pnpm install # install dependencies
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - pnpm-lock.yaml
    paths:
      - .pnpm-store
  only:
    - develop
    - /\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/

test:
  stage: test
  tags:
      - node:LTS
  coverage: /All files[^|]*\|[^|]*\s+([\d\.]+)/
  dependencies:
    - install
  script:
    - pnpm test:ci
  only:
    - develop
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit: coverage/junit-report.xml
      coverage_report: 
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: coverage/coverage-final.json
```

As you can imagine, it doens't work. In test stage, I get this error:

```
$ pnpm test:ci
/bin/bash: line 140: pnpm: command not found
```

Do I have to add the `before_script` in every stage whereI want to use `pnpm`? I saw many examples on the internet, one of them [Here](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/1174), but I don't know if I have to add this

```yaml
default:
  image: node:lts-alpine
  cache: &cache
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
    paths:
      - .pnpm-store
      - ./node_modules
      - apps/web/node_modules
    policy: pull


before_script:
  - npm i -g pnpm
  - pnpm config set store-dir .pnpm-store
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have pnpm running in our Gitlab CI pipelines. What we do is run `before_script` and add pnpm to every task. I'm not sure if it's the best way to go about it, but it works. My guess is that since each job/task runs in isolation, it doesn't know aobut the previous task's installation of pnpm. It can access the cache though because you instruct it to, but that doesn't mean that the pnpm CLI is installed.

Taking our configuration and applying it to your example would be as below.

Two things to add:

1. `before_script` to install pnpm CLI to this runner instance
2. `cache` to utilize the cache you have populated in `install` step

```
install:
  stage: install
  tags:
      - node:LTS
  before_script:
    - corepack enable
    - corepack prepare pnpm@latest-7 --activate
    - pnpm config set store-dir .pnpm-store
  script:
    - pnpm install # install dependencies
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - pnpm-lock.yaml
    paths:
      - .pnpm-store
  only:
    - develop
    - /\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/

test:
  stage: test
  tags:
      - node:LTS
  coverage: /All files[^|]*\|[^|]*\s+([\d\.]+)/
  dependencies: # this one we don't have, not sure if you need to keep it?
    - install
  before_script: # add this
    - corepack enable
    - corepack prepare pnpm@latest-7 --activate
    - pnpm config set store-dir .pnpm-store
  cache: # tell Gitlab to pull from cache
    - key:
          files:
              - pnpm-lock.yaml
          prefix: pnpm-cache
      paths:
          - .pnpm-cache
      policy: pull
  script:
    - pnpm test:ci
  only:
    - develop
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit: coverage/junit-report.xml
      coverage_report: 
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: coverage/coverage-final.json
```

Answer (score 1):

You used to be able to add a `before_script` at the top level to execute something before each job's `script` (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76717466/7964751)).  The global `before_script` [has been deprecated](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#globally-defined-image-services-cache-before_script-after_script) in favor of the [`default` section](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#default), which can have a `before_script` (example from Gitlab docs [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#set-a-default-before_script-or-after_script-for-all-jobs)).

To enable `pnpm` before each CI job, you could do something like this:

```
default:
  before_script:
  - corepack enable
  - corepack prepare pnpm@latest-8 --activate
  - pnpm config set store-dir .pnpm-store
```

Be careful with this approach, though, because you can easily override the `before_script` in a given job.  See below from the [Gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#default) that `before_script` in an individual job overrides the default `before_script`:

> When the pipeline is created, each default is copied to all jobs that don’t have that keyword defined.
> If a job already has one of the keywords configured, the configuration in the job takes precedence and is not replaced by the default.

Finally, if the `default` section doesn't work for you for some reason (e.g., you're inheriting defaults from somewhere else), you could get almost the same thing by using [YAML anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#yaml-anchors-for-scripts).  For example:

```
.prepare-pnpm: &prepare-pnpm
  - corepack enable
  - corepack prepare pnpm@latest-8 --activate
  - pnpm config set store-dir .pnpm-store

install:
  stage: install
  script:
    - *prepare-pnpm
    - pnpm install

test:
  stage: test
  dependencies:
    - install
  script:
    - *prepare-pnpm
    - pnpm test:ci
```

Reference:  I learned a lot of this from the related discussion [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2301).

Answer (score 0):

Add `before_script` section in global scope like this:

```yaml
image: node:18-alpine3.18

cache:
  key:
    files:
      - pnpm-lock.yaml
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    - .pnpm-store/

before_script:
  - corepack enable
  - corepack prepare pnpm@latest-8 --activate
  - pnpm config set store-dir .pnpm-store

stages:
  - build
  - lint
  - test
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - staging
    - production
  script:
    - pnpm install
  tags:
    - shared

lint:code:
  stage: lint
  needs: [build]
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - staging
    - production
  script:
    - pnpm lint:quiet
  tags:
    - shared

lint:commit:
  stage: lint
  needs: [build]
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - staging
    - production
  before_script: []    # ignore when `pnpm` it's not used
  script:
    - echo -e "${CI_COMMIT_TITLE}\n${CI_COMMIT_DESCRIPTION}" | npx commitlint

[...]
```